How to define power in case of multiple tests that complements with family-wise error rate?
Family-wise error rate is defined as the probability of rejecting at least one true null hypothesis, that is, the probability of committing at least one Type-1 error.
How do we define the power in case of multiple tests?
Power, by definition for one test, is obtained like this: Calculate Pr$($Type-2 error$)$, that is, the probability of failing to reject false null hypothesis. Then, calculate the power using $1 -$ Pr$($Type-2 error$)$.
How does this definition generalizes to multiple tests?
In case of multiple tests, we can define Pr$($Type-2 error$)$ as the probability of failing to reject at least one false null hypothesis, and get power using $1 -$ Pr$($Type-2 error$)$.
Alternatively, we can also define power in case of multiple tests to be: the probability of rejecting at least one false null hypothesis.
I'm new to multiple testing, and I'm not sure how prevalent (if they are) these definitions are, and which one to use in which scenarios. Any help will be much appreciated. Recommendations for books or other sources are also appreciated. Thanks!
